Error Hosting express app in digital ocean
I wanted to host my Express app in Digital Ocean but I couldn't do so because of the following error:
 this.INTERNAL = new FirebaseNamespaceInternals(appStore ?? new lifecycle_1.AppStore());

I tried to host my Express app in Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

Enough information is not available to debug this but looks same as this issue. Try upgrading your node version to 16.
Provide enough information & screenshot of error message so your issue can be understood better.

When I tested it locally , it work well but while hosting it didn't . I tried it by changing node versions but it didn't effect the errors.

https://ibb.co/FHV4HCG                                                                                                                                           this url contain screenshot of difference between locally host express app result and digital ocean host result.

What node version are you using?
